# macOS Sublime Text 3: How do I disable one window / tabbed windows?

Tags: sublimetext3

Not to long ago (well, maybe months and months), Sublime 3 has started launching as a singular window with tabbed windows that have their own tabs. I despise this approach. See screen shot:
[image]

How do I disable this behavior?

- Version 3.1.1 build 3176

The only Packages I have installed are:

```
A File Icon
Groovy Snippets
Material Theme 
Package Control
Pretty JSON
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular feature is something that's happening as a result of your using MacOS (i.e. it's not something that Sublime does natively; the OS is doing it on your behalf).

In the general case most MacOS applications should have native menu items to combine windows together like this at the user's request in combination with the `Prefer tabs when opening documents` setting in the `Dock` area of the system preferences.

Sublime doesn't support the native menu items for this (yet), so it relies solely on the setting; having it set to `Always` (and also `In Full Screen Only`, but this tends to cause problems with Sublime) makes MacOS automatically "tab" new windows. Setting that setting to `Manually` stops this from happening.

This is also somewhat controlled by the Theme that you're using in Sublime. For MacOS, a Sublime theme can theme the menu bar of the window to match the overall application theme. Behind the scenes, this makes Sublime declare to MacOS that it wants to be in charge of displaying it's own window, which stops the system from automatically combining windows together.

An example of a theme that does this is the `Adaptive` theme that ships with Sublime.

Comment: "Setting that setting to Manually stops this from happening." -- Thank you! That did solve this.  Interesting. No wonder I couldn't find it anywhere in Sublime. It never happened on any other app I run, only Sublime.

Comment: Yeah it's caught a few people by surprise. I think apps generally tend to fall into the "support this natively" or "don't support this at all" type category, but Sublime hovers somewhere in between. It's not overtly doing anything to make this happen, but it's not blocking it from happening either.